# "Only Their Own" Sharepoint Online Repository

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'd like users to only be able to delete their own files, but edit and view everything else. Is this possible in Sharepoint Online? I've read a lot of stuff about 2007 being able to do this, but nothing that allows me to do it today.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: You need to set permission to each files. All user will have read permission on all files and files which he has upload having contribute permission. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this article saved in my bookmarks which is doing some what similar to your requirement. The article is for SharePoint 2010, but i assume it will work for SharePoint online also.

[SharePoint 2010: Start a Workflow on Item Delete](http://blogs.sharepoint911.com/blogs/jennifer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=50)

The Steps are as below:

1. Create a document library
2. Create a permission level without delete option
3. Assign this newly created permission for all users.
4. Now create a workflow which will check the initiator of the workflow is same as owner then delete the document. To delete the document you will need to use Impersonation step as initiator will not have delete rights.
5. Once workflow is created, use designer to create custom action of "List Item menu" and start a workflow using that custom action.

To get the initiator of the workflow, please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131238/in-sharepoint-designers-workflow-editor-how-do-i-get-the-workflow-initiators-us). the workflow initiator variable is available OOTB in SharePoint Designer.

I have not tried this. It is just a collections of bookmarks which i have with me.

Comment: No need to do this much level of customization.

Comment: @KaushalKhamar Your answer seems to be very vague. "You need to set permission to each files." I have repositories with 1000 files in them. That is too much.

Comment: Thanks p s, but I think this is a flimsy way to do it. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event handlers to control edit permissions.

You can have an event handler that registers an event using the **SPEventReceiverType.ItemDeleting** methods, and then use code to control whether the delete should be allowed.

This is extremely powerful, because you can make security decision based on any metadata of a list or item, without affecting the view rendering performance.

**And no need to set permission to each document**

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by following.

1. Create a Document library
2. Create custom permission level with-out delete permission
3. Break the library permissions and apply this custom permission
4. Create a workflow to replace the permissions by following the below article
   http://www.sharepointusecases.com/2010/03/configure-item-level-permissions-for-document-libraries-part-2/

It's with impersonation step, will change the permissions as you want.

5. Trigger this workflow when an item created. It will execute when an item created and the new permissions will be applied to your documents.